# Disable italic in math environment

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I have one quick question, is there a way to disable the italic font in general in the math environment?

cheers

Comment: Not really. It's quite easy to instruct TeX to use upright letters in math mode, but no upright font is tailored for use as math letters, so spacing, subscripts and superscripts would be bad.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question clearly: do you want *all* math to be upright? Or in just `equation` or inline (`$ some math$`) or similar?